# Sign in with Google, OAuth2, how do I verify the user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have an app on Rails and I am trying to implement sign in with Google as my primary way of logging in.

I am using the `google-api-ruby-client`. The login page has the Google button linked to the auth uri, generated using client secrets.

1. I have managed to get the access token from the user using `fetch_access_token!` with the 'email' and 'profile' scopes.
2. I am hitting the `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo` for the user's name, email and Google id.
3. I have not yet figured out how to use the refresh token yet.

However, I am confused how to identify the user. For example, the first time a user signs in:

1. Authenticate with Google and I will save the Google user id, email, access token, and refresh token into the database.
2. `session[:access_token] = auth_client.access_token`
3. `session[:current_user] = google_id` (this is from the `userinfo` endpoint)

Subsequently when the user goes to any page on the website, I will have a `before_filter :authenticate` method that checks `session[:access_token]`, queries the database for the same `acccess_token` and see if the `google_id` returned from the database matches `session[:current_user]`.

When the access token is expired while the user is still using my website, presumably I can use the refresh token to get a new access token and update the session and database information. I can do this since I still have the user's id in the session.

When the user comes back later on to the website, I can get a new access token again and update the access token and refresh token in the database and session since the user will have to log in again via Google and I can match up the email or id in the database.

3 questions:

1. Is this an acceptable way of authenticating the user? If not, what is the correct way?
2. I can safely substitute the `google_id` with my own randomly generated id, right?
3. When on StackOverflow or Facebook, we don't have to re-sign in as we are already signed in. How do I implement this?

Comment: Why don't you use https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2 that is built on top of OmniAuth and makes the whole process much easier?

Comment: I will check that out and report back. It does look easier. Does omniauth-google-oauth2 come with `Devise`?

Comment: Yes, devise does support OmniAuth. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3A-Overview Here is my article on OAuth 2 just in case: http://www.sitepoint.com/rails-authentication-oauth-2-0-omniauth/